# Smartctl script to write zeros

Tags: bash, hard-drive, scripts, smart

So i have an old hdd that was badsectors and i wrong the following script to write zeros in badsectors that smartctl finds. The question is will this help the read/write errors or it is futile?

the script (btw sorry of any eye-gougings first writen script):

```
a="$(smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb | grep '# 1' | awk '{print  $9}')"
smartctl -t short /dev/sdb
clear
echo $a
b="$(smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb | grep '# 1' | awk '{print  $5}')"
echo $b
until [[ $a = 0 ]];do
if [[ $b == *Compl* && $a == 0% ]]
        then
            exit
    else
            if [[ $b == *Compl* ]]
                    then
                    echo writting zeros
                    X="$(smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb | grep 'read failure'| grep '# 1' | awk '{print  $10}')"
                    Y=$((X / 8))
                    Z=${Y%.*}
                    echo $Y
                    dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb conv=sync bs=4096 count=1 seek=$Y
                    smartctl -t short /dev/sdb
            fi
            sleep 10
            c="$(smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb | grep '# 1' | awk '{print  $9}')"
            d="$(smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb | grep '# 1' | awk '{print  $5}')"
                    until [[ $c != $a ]] || [[ $d != $b ]];do
                            sleep 10
                            c="$(smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb | grep '# 1' | awk '{print  $9}')"
                            d="$(smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb | grep '# 1' | awk '{print  $5}')"
                            clear
                            echo $c
                            echo $d
                            echo ZZZZzzzzzZZZZ
                    done
            clear
            echo wake up time $(date +"%H:%M:%S")
            a=$c
            b=$d
            echo $a
            echo $b

fi
done
echo done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically futile. It might help for a short while, but if your disk has bad sectors, then it's only going to get more bad sectors with time. It's best to buy a new disk, and/or get that one replaced if it is under warranty. If it's not under warranty, then back up the good data to a good disk, write 0s to the bad disk at least 10 times, and take it to a place where it will be recycled properly.

Comment: Thanks for your quite and straight answer. As a follow up, how can i mark the sectors as bad so the os wont write to them?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/291570/mark-bad-sectors-on-hard-drive-without-formating