# Bug: Unable to handle kernel paging request at fffffffffdffffff after Grub menu, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, kernel, filesystem

I have a dual boot system installed following blog - [Ubuntu 16.04 with windows 10](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) along with an additional swap partition. It was working fine for several months and something like `no boot device detected` appeared after a shutdown (I'm not sure about the reason, but I had installed somethings Software Updater suggested). On the next restart, monitor went to power saving mode and I had to shutdown using the power button. It remained the same for two other attempts, then I reconnected everything from RAM, SATA cables, power cables etc and cleaned dust all over.

Now, system shows some message like:

```
watchdog=1 notification connection refused
```

And cursor blinks on a black screen. Some type of repeated messages are printed at almost same time intervals. Starting words are:

```
Oops
Modules linked in
CPU
Hardware name
Task
---end trace ---
```

Along with some HEX codes and `?` symbols.

If I tried to login with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F*</kbd>, it prints:

```
/dev/sda3: recovering journal
/dev/sda3: clean *** / *** files, *** / *** blocks
```

On the next keypress:

```
agetty[949]: segfault at *** ip *** sp *** error 14 in locale-archeive[***]
```

I have tried to see the contents from Grub menu. There is `(hd0,msdos3)/` with `/boot/grub` and other system directories. `(hd0,msdos2)` and `(hd0,msdos4)` with `/home` contents and `windows` partitions. Remaining `(hd0,msdos1)` shows `unknown filesystem`.

How can I correct the errors? Or at least copy the contents and reinstall Ubuntu?

#### Update1

Booting from live USB shows:

```
32 bit relocation outside of kernel!
-- system halted!
```

#### Update2

On upstart:

```
/dev/sda3 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Deleted inode 3670025 has zero dtime. FIXED.
/dev/sda3: 373516/9158656 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 2754152/36621093 blocks.
fsck exited with status code 1
[ 19.752709 ] upstart[1]: segfault at 5 ip ...
...
[ 19.768565 ] --- [end Kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000b
```

Comment: Van you boot an old kernel

Comment: sounds like HDD failure. did you run  a SMART test on the drive?

Comment: @Panther it also fails, even a bootable USB get stucks! :(

Comment: @ravery SMART test ,  `badblocks`, `fsck`, everything tried

Comment: Does windows boot?

Comment: @Panther no, it also shows some error and restart it self.

Comment: will a LiveCD boot?  possibly bad RAM or CPU cache.

Comment: @ravery may be, I have read somewhere the word `cache`. I will add the messages shown while booting live USB.

Comment: @KrIsHnA What did the SMART test say? Where Windows fails to boot too, that suggests a hardware issue.

Comment: @WJAndrea I did SMART from another HDD and it said this HDD is healthy.  Then I did `badblocks` too. Referred this link - https://askubuntu.com/a/490549/300767

Comment: Even thought the result was `PASSED` there were errors, see https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ksvylT8_W7cMKZEAy5AqVa_VGlmFllEZHSWybNV5dG4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ravery Is there any hope?

Comment: @WJAndrea please see the result in the link above

Comment: is this a laptop or desktop? looks like bearing age may be causing speed variation thus read errors. With desktop computers I have had success in extending drive life by mounting the drive on it's side so the disk rides on the thrust bearings, thus stabilizing disk speed.

Comment: @ravery Desktop is old one, core2Duo. HDD is still under warranty, in use for last 8 months.

Comment: if it's under warranty, I'd get another drive.

Comment: I bought a 4TB HDD, tried to install Ubuntu and got the same error as of `Update1` and then realized one of four RAMs was causing error. Anyway, my fs fixing attempts ruined ntfs partitions and `windows 10` is missing on `grub menu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone will land here frustrated the way I was, so save yourself before trying to recover a `bad file system` / `boot device error`.

I was having a `bad RAM` at one of the 4 slots. So, I would like to remind you to do a `memtest` from the `grub menu` before you proceed anything with Harddisk drive.

Also, you may be lucky enough to use the error-free part of RAM, read section :-

> [BADRAM setting in Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BadRAM)

If you proceed to do more tests with HDDs, you may end up with file system errors which are not easy to recover.

[see the comment here](https://blog.hartwork.org/?p=1712)