# Is there an application/way to fix or confine bad sectors with Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, hard-drive

My hardisk has 1880 bad sectors and I am beginning to realize that it about to fail.

Is there a way using my Ubuntu OS to fix or at least partition off the part of my HD where most of these sectors are?

Comment: maybe it helps you
http://askubuntu.com/questions/241944/how-to-fix-the-hard-drive-bad-sector

Comment: 1880 bad sectors is too many to repair, you need to stop using the drive immediately.

Answer (score 2):

No doubt this is a duplicate, but the answer needs to be put up front:

***Replace that hard disk NOW!!*** Bad sectors cannot be fixed. A small number can be worked around, but this is done automatically by the firmware in the hard disk; you should never see any sign that they actually exist unless you run a SMART test on the disk. When you start seeing bad sectors, it means that the disk is failing. The disk may continue to be usable (in a limited way) for anywhere from no time at all to months, but the problem is that these failures can and often do escalate very rapidly and without further warning -- the bad sectors *are* the warning. Thus, you should go to a store *today,* buy a new disk, and copy your data off the bad disk *today.* Don't mail-order a new disk to save $10, because the extra time for delivery of the disk could be the time in which you go from 1,880 bad sectors to 1,880,000 bad sectors.